# How to convert Sql inner query to Linq for sum of column

Tags: sql, linq

How to Convert this sql query to Linq.

```
select sum(OutstandingAmt)from IvfReceiptDetails where IvfReceiptId IN(select IvfReceiptId from IvfReceipts where PatientId = 'SI-49650')
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easier to translate SQL using query comprehension syntax instead of lambda syntax.

General rules:

1. Translate inner queries into separate query variables
2. Translate SQL phrases in LINQ phrase order
3. Use table aliases as range variables, or if none, create range variables from table names
4. Translate `IN` to `Contains`
5. Translate SQL functions such as `DISTINCT` or `SUM` into function calls on the entire query.

Here is the code:

```
var IvfReceiptIds = from IvfReceipt in IvfReceipts
                    where IvfReceipt.PatientId = "SI-49650"
                    select IvfReceipt.IvfReceiptId;

var OutstandingAmtSum = (from IvfReceiptDetail in IvfReceiptDetails
                         where IvfReciptIds.Contains(IvfReceiptDetail.IvfReceiptId)
                         select IvfReceiptDetail.OutstandingAmt).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, First get all `IvfReceiptId` in `array` based on your inner query used in where condition then check `contains`. Change name of your `_context` if it's different.

```
var arrIvfReceiptId = _context.IvfReceiptDetails.Where(p=>p.PatientId == "SI-49650").ToArray();
var sum = (from ird in _context.IvfReceiptDetails.Where(p=> arrIvfReceiptId.Contains(p.IvfReceiptId))
select OutstandingAmt).Sum();
```